# Flutter - How to change the color of the selected container? The container has a tab

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs

I am trying to create a tab bar, and the length is 4.

Tabs have specific heights and widths. So I wrap it with the container. Each container has a tab.

How to change the color of container as selected tab?

The container(tab) color should be gray and the selected color should be blue. How to achieve this? I tried but didn't get the exact result I wanted.

Here's what I get:

[image]

Sample code:

```
DefaultTabController(
            length: 4, // length of tabs
            initialIndex: 0,
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 300,
child: Column(children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, left: 5, right: 5),
                          child: TabBar(
                            isScrollable: true,
                            labelColor: const Color(0xff000000),
                            labelPadding:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 5),
                            indicator: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.circular(10), // Creates border
                                color: const Color(0xff77e8d9)),
                            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                            tabs: [
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                        10), // Creates border
                                    color: const Color(0xfff4f4f4)),
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  height: 40,
                                  width: 110,
                                  child: Tab(
                                    child: Row(children: [
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                                        child: Text('Featured',
                                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                              fontSize: 15,
                                              letterSpacing: 0.3,
                                            )),
                                      ),
                                      const Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1),
                                        child: Icon(
                                          Icons.favorite,
                                          color: Color(0xffef5145),
                                          size: 21,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ]),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                   Container(child: Tab()), //like above
                   Container(child: Tab()), 
                   Container(child: Tab()), 
                   Container(child: Tab()), 
                     ),
                     ),
                     ]),
                     ),

        TabBarView(children: [
                      Container(),
                      Container(),
                      Container(),
                      Container(),
                    ]),
              ),)))),
))
             }}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to wrap your container in a GestureDector widget and for onTap change the color (declare a variable in your class outside of the build or init method) and then set color for your container to that variable so that it can change and reflect when it is pressed or selected.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can you give an example, please?